# Fazer alertas em uma página com javascript

Tags: javascript

Olá! 
Tenho que pegar a data que está no banco de dados e fazer um alerta em javascript dois dias antes daquela data.

Como faço para colocar esse alerta em um box com javascript no sistema?

Comment: O que você já tentou fazer?

Comment: Qual linguagem *back-end* você está utilizando? Geralmente pra fazer isso você vai precisar mais do que só **JavaScript**.

Comment: @PauloImon a linguagem que está sendo utilizada é o PHP.
A minha dúvida é só como fazer esse time no javascript.

Comment: Se você quiser exibir o `alert()`, pode fazer a comparação das datas no **PHP** e em seguida passar alguma *flag* pro seu código dentro da *tag* `<script>`. Não tem total necessidade de utilizar **AJAX** e nem CRON JOBS.

Comment: É isso aí mesmo @PauloImon. Só que eu quero tipo criar uma div e quero que apareça esse alerta no box da div. Não em uma uma caixa de alert do javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No **PHP**, você poderia ter algo mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php
    // Instancia o objeto MySQLi e faz a conexão com a base de dados
    // (Altere os dados com as credenciais do seu servidor MySQL)
    $conexao = new mysqli('host', 'root', 'pswd', 'db');

    // Declara a flag p/ exibição de mensagens como desativada
    $alerta = FALSE;

    // Consulta de exemplo
    // (Altere a consulta conforme a sua tabela)
    $sql = "SELECT `data` FROM `tabela` WHERE `id` = 1 LIMIT 1";

    // Executa a consulta
    $consulta = $conexao->query($sql);

    // Gera o resultado da consulta
    $resultado = $consulta->fetch_array();

    // Pega a data atual e converte p/ padrão timestamp do Unix
    $hoje = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));

    // Converte a data do banco p/ padrão timestamp do Unix
    $data = strtotime($resultado['data']);

    // Verifica se a data ainda não foi ultrapassada
    if ($hoje < $data)
    {
        // Calcula a diferença em segundos
        $diferenca = $data - $hoje;

        // Converte a diferença p/ dias
        $dias = (int) floor($diferenca / (60 * 60 * 24));

        // Verifica se a quantidade de dias atende sua condição
        if ($dias <= 2)
        {
            // Ativa a flag p/ exibir mensagem
            $alerta = TRUE;
        }
    }
```

Agora no seu código **HTML**, você pode gerar a mensagem usando uma simples condição do **PHP**:

```
<div>
    <?php if ($alerta) { ?>
    <p>Atenção! Mensagem de alerta!</p>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Referência:

[Calculando a diferença em dias entre duas datas - Blog Thiago Belem](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/calculando-a-diferenca-em-dias-entre-duas-datas)

Comment: Agradeço! É essa ideia aí mesmo...